# Proving the convergence of a sequence to a limit from another sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Currently taking Real Analysis 1. Working on proving convergence of sequences. I have been struggling general with how to approach these problems, so the ask is help with the problem in addition to a critique of the approach.

The Problem: Let $u_{n}$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} (u_{n+1} - u_{n}) = l$$ where $l$ is a real number.$$$$
Show that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}(u_{n}/n)=l$$

After spending some time thinking about this, I feel as though I have some grasp of why this might be the case. If the distance between $u_{n}$ and $u_{n+1}$ approaches a limit then the distance from one term to the other is approaching a constant rate. It would makes sense that if this is the case then the ratio of $u_{n}/n$ would also approach a constant because the rate of growth of $u_{n}$ with respect to $n$ is constant from the previous statement.

In terms of actually approaching the problem I think that I need to find an N such that $| u_{n}/n-l|<\epsilon$ from the knowledge that $|(u_{n+1} - u_{n})-l|<\epsilon$

Trying to solve the problem at this point has mostly been shots in the dark, random applications of the triangle inequality, and frustration.

As stated previously in addition to help with the problem I would appreciate some insight into the thought process that led you to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to write $u_n$ in terms of the differences $u_{n+1}-u_n$. We can write $u_n=u_1+(u_2-u_1)+\cdots+(u_n-u_{n-1})$. Let $v_1=u_1, v_2=u_2-u_1$ etc. Then $\frac {u_n} n=\frac {v_1+v_2+\cdots+ v_n} n$. It is given that $v_n \to l$. The fact that $\frac {u_n} n \to l$ now follows from Cesaro's Theorem.